# Any idea on the simplest graphing technique?

Tags: android

I need to create a View that represents an x/y axis. I will read in 9 separate sets of (x,y) coordinates and will have 9 checkboxes, one for each set of data. When the user presses the check boxes the different waves will appear.

I have done research and found three possibilities: google charts, achartengine, and Canvas.

Does anyone have any ideas at what I could use for the simplest implementation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use AChartEngine rather than drawing to canvas.
You can download the library, javadocs and a demo application [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list).
The main advantage of using AChartEngine is that you won't need a data connection for rendering charts.

There are tutorials on youtube on getting started with AChartEngine. The library is free and open-source.

Comment: Yes Dan is absolutely right, Use AChartEngine lib instead of drawing to Canvas.

Comment: @Dan I have looked at the demo application and have started to implement this in my code. I am new to Android Development however and have an inquiry: The example uses ListActivities only, does this matter? I have looked into it myself and it seems as if it wouldn't matter at all whether I use an Activity or a ListActivity, I would just like clarification.

Comment: The ListActivity is only for the main menu, for selecting the chart you want to open.